# How to minimize a summation function

Tags: summation, algorithms, absolute-value, recursive-algorithms

My question is: How do we minimize a function like this with find a constant number for x?

in another word, we have a set and "i" is a member of that set and we should find a constant number as x to minimize that function
[My problem function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nw4W.png)

Comment: Take the median.

Comment: Thank you, dear.

Comment: Please use the body of your Question to give a self-contained formulation of the problem you want help with.  Use $\LaTeX$ to [post typeset mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) like summations.  Linking to mere images is suboptimal and may give Readers the impression you are not interested in contributing good content here, and perhaps not even in understanding the problems you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Yves says, take the median. Proof:
$$f(x)=\sum_i |i-x|=\sum_{i \geqslant x} (i-x) + \sum_{i < x} (x-i)  $$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{i \geqslant x} (-1) + \sum_{i < x} (+1)  $$
which is the number of data points less than $x$ LESS the number of data points greater than $x$.
To minimize $f(x)$ we want its derivative to be zero, which gives us the median.